# Check for specific integer in a row WHERE user = $name

Tags: php, mysql, database, integer, compare

Here is what I wanna do: User can comment up to five times a day (in code I use 60 seconds to see the result quicker). 
However I seem to make a wrong comparison, because right now it always gives me back true. So even if the counter is above 5, it still counts up instead of stopping there (for 60 seconds). 
Any input is appreciated. Down below is the code I use.

```
<?php
$DB_HostName = "";
$DB_Name = "";
$DB_User = "";
$DB_Pass = "";
$DB_Table = "";

$name = mysql_escape_string($_GET['name']);
set_time_limit(0);

$con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die (mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

 if ($name[CommentCounterReset] === 5) //or if ("CommentCounterReset === 5 WHERE Name = $name)? {
   echo "You already wrote five comments.";
   set_time_limit(60);  
   $sql = "UPDATE table SET CommentCounterReset = CommentCounterReset-5 WHERE Name = '$name'";
}  else {
 $sql = "UPDATE table SET CommentCounterReset = CommentCounterReset+1 WHERE Name = '$name'";
        echo "Comment accepted.";

 }

$res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());

   mysql_close($con);
if ($res) {
}else{
}// end else
?>
```

Comment: Careful.... use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to prevent against SQL injection.  `mysql_escape_string()` can be worked around in certain conditions.  It would be best if you dropped `mysql_*` entirely, as it is deprecated, and went to something else, like PDO.  Then you can use prepared queries.

Comment: If i got it right, when the user submits the comment submits also a hidden field with name="name['CommentCounterReset']" and value the CommentCounterReset?

Comment: Why are you playing around with set time limit? Does that do what you think it does? http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: FYI you should really quote your strings, i.e. `$name['CommentCounterReset']` instead of `$name[CommentCounterReset]` and enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to see any notices about bad stuff like unquoted strings and undefined variables.

Comment: Thanks Thiefmaster, edited and added it. @Nanne Because I want it to do something after a specific amount of time.

Comment: That is not what the function is for. It doesn't make your script sleep or wait. It makes your script time-limit be higher. It has nothing to with how long it actually runs, but if you go over the limit it will throw an error. Check out the manual, because I still think it doesn't do what you think it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run the query after a wait time with this command:

```
 set_time_limit(60);
```

This makes the maximum run time of your script 60 seconds, but doesn't actually do anything more. It changes a setting so your script *could* run a maximum of 1 minute, but doesn't actually make it run.

You could do it with `sleep` but you shouldn't If you want to do it for a day, that means your script would run for a day (it can, sleep doesn't "count" as it is a system call).

Better write a certain time to your database and check against that. If the user wants to comment you check

Check if the user has 5 comments.

1. Yes? check the time
   1.if it is in the past, post the comment and reset the counter.

   1. if it is in the future, don't post the comment.
2. No? increase the counter and post the comment

   1. did you increase it to 5? then set the date to +60 seconds (or +1 day).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. I guess I would do it with a timestamp then and check against it? So if the time is olders than 24 hours Ill reset it?

Comment: yep, a timestamp would be the easiest. Just compare the time if the counter is 5, and set the time if the counter just became 5.

Comment: Thanks! So here is how I did it. However it still keeps going up after 5. So the counter does not stop. if  ($name['CommentCounterReset'] >= 5)
    {  if (time() - $_SESSION['time'] <= 60*60*24){
       echo "You already wrote five comments.";
         }
    else {
     $sql = "UPDATE table SET CommentCounterReset = CommentCounterReset-5 WHERE Name = '$name'";   
    }     
    }  else {
     $sql = "UPDATE table SET CommentCounterReset = CommentCounterReset+1 WHERE Name = '$name'";
        echo "Your comment has been added.";
    }

Answer (score 0):

make correction here,it must greater than equal to

```
if ($name[CommentCounterReset] >= 5)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,however it did not fix the problem I am having.