# Draw a comparison between an integer in a specific row and a count

Tags: php, mysql, database, integer, compare

This is a follow-up question to this one: [Check for specific integer in a row WHERE user = $name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544658/check-for-specific-integer-in-a-row-where-user-name)

I want a user to be able to comment on my site for exactly five times a day. After this five times, the user has to wait 24 hours. 
In order to accomplish that I raise a counter in my MYSQL database, right next to the user. 
So where the name of the user is, there is where the counter gets raised. When it reaches 5 it should stop counting and reset after 24 hours. In order to check the time I use a timestamp. I check if the timestamp is older than 24 hours. If that is the case, the counter gets reseted (-5) and the user can comment again. In order to do that, I use the following code, however it never stops at five, my guess is that my comparison is wrong somehow:

```
$counter = mysql_query("SELECT FROM table VALUES CommentCounterReset WHERE Name = '$name'");

if(!isset($_SESSION['ts'])); {
    $_SESSION['ts'] = time();
}

if  ($counter >= 5) { 
    if (time() - $_SESSION['ts'] <= 60*60*24){
        echo "You already wrote five comments.";
    }
    else {
        $sql = "UPDATE table SET CommentCounterReset = CommentCounterReset-5 WHERE Name = '$name'";   
    }     
}  
else {
 $sql = "UPDATE table SET CommentCounterReset = CommentCounterReset+1 WHERE Name = '$name'";
    echo "Your comment has been added.";
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't actually execute the SQL query stored in `$counter` (and that is not a valid SQL query, either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should let him add comments 5 times a day, not after 24 hours:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `Name`, `timestamp`, `CommentCounterReset` FROM `table` WHERE `Name`=:name");
$stmt->execute(array(':name' => $_GET['name']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$lastComment = $row['timestamp']; // timestamp from database and not from $_SESSION because $_SESSION get's destroyed.
$countComments = $row['CommentCounterReset']; // number of comments added

$row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
if(!$row_count){
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` VALUES(0, :name, :timestamp, 1)");
    $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $_GET['name'], ':timestamp' => date('U')));
    echo "Your comment has been added.";
} else {
    if($countComments > 4 && date('d') == date('d', $lastComment)){ // if number of comments are greater than 4 and is same day
        echo "You already wrote five comments today.";
    } else {
        if(date('d') != date('d', $lastComment)){ // if there are different days, reset the counter to 1
            $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `table` SET `CommentCounterReset` = 1, `timestamp`=:timestamp WHERE `Name`=:name");
            $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $_GET['name'], ':timestamp' => date('U')));
        } else { // if it's same day increase counter with 1
            $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `table` SET `CommentCounterReset` = `CommentCounterReset`+1 WHERE `Name`=:name");
            $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $_GET['name']));
        }
        echo "Your comment has been added.";
    }
}
```

for `mysql_*` but I'm highly discouraging it!

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('test', $link);

$stmt = mysql_query("SELECT `Name`, `timestamp`, `CommentCounterReset` FROM `table` WHERE `Name`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])."'");
$num = mysql_num_rows($stmt);

if(!$num){
    $stmt = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` VALUES(0, '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])."', '".date('U')."', 1)");
    echo "Your comment has been added.";
} else {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($stmt);
    $lastComment = $row['timestamp']; // timestamp from database and not from $_SESSION because $_SESSION get's destroyed.
    $countComments = $row['CommentCounterReset']; // number of comments added

    if($countComments > 4 && date('d') == date('d', $lastComment)){ // if number of comments are greater than 4 and is same day
        echo "You already wrote five comments today.";
    } else {
        if(date('d') != date('d', $lastComment)){ // if there are different days, reset the counter to 1
            $stmt = mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `CommentCounterReset` = 1, `timestamp`='".date('U')."' WHERE `Name`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])."'");
        } else { // if it's same day increase counter with 1
            $stmt = mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `CommentCounterReset` = `CommentCounterReset`+1 WHERE `Name`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])."'");
        }
        echo "Your comment has been added.";
    }
}
```

my `table`:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CommentCounterReset` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: Hey, first of all thank you very, very much for this code. :) It is greatly appreciated. However I did not use PDO yet, so maybe I am doing something wrong. In order to call it, I just do it like I normally would, right? (e.g. www.myserver.com/Myphp.PHP?name=myName)? Right now, I get the echo "Your comment has been added" back, but The counter stays at 0. Do you maybe have an idea why that could be?

Comment: I recommend you to start using PDO as `www.myserver.com/Myphp.PHP?name=myName` is highly vulnerable to SQL injections. Hoever I did not test this code but it should work. Your queries would be `Name='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])."'` instead of the last part of each SQL.

Comment: Also make sure you have timestamp row in your table as INT

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work, however it always gives me back the echo "Your comment has been added", _but_ always resets it to zero. I don't know why. Also when trying to put TIMESTAMP to in and not CURRENT_TIMESTAMP it tells me that its not a default value.

Comment: I don't know how your timestamp is stored into db. I told you to make it INT.

Comment: Yes, like I said, when I try to make it INT, it tells me that its not a default value for TIMESTAMP.

Comment: INT in database. not in script

Comment: Okay thanks, did it like you said, but the problem still persists, that I get back "Your comment has been added", but it always resets the count to zero. Only this line         $stmt = mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `CommentCounterReset` = 1, `timestamp`='".date('U')."' WHERE `Name`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])."'");
seems to gets called.

Comment: it should reset the count to 1.

Comment: let me run that script and see what I get

Comment: Tested, works. I've added a check to see if the row exists in db. In rest the script worked as it should.

Comment: Dude thanks so much for the extended explanation, it really helped me alot. It now works flawlesly :)

Answer (score 1):

You write:

```
$counter = mysql_query("SELECT FROM table VALUES CommentCounterReset WHERE Name = '$name'");

if  ($counter >= 5) {
```

...but `$counter` is a *resource*, not the result of the query. So the comparison is flawed.

You ought to run the query and then fetch the value:

```
$exec = mysql_query("SELECT CommentCounterReset FROM table WHERE Name='$name';");
// Insert considerations about SQL injection and benefits of PDO here :-)
$tuple = mysql_fetch_assoc($exec);         // Might also do with fetch_array
$counter = $tuple['CommentCounterReset'];  // and $tuple[0]
```

Perhaps, though, a better way to ensure the limit isn't exceeded would be to leave most work to SQL. You store the name and the date of the post; the total number of rows in the table is at most 5*number_of_users . This way you check for posts in the same day (not a 24 hour period).

```
// Clean the table. This will be done frequently, and it will be very fast
mysql_query("DELETE FROM comment_counters WHERE day < date(now());");
// It is also possible to add "... AND name='$name'" to the WHERE to reduce
// the number of affected rows; in this case the first version of the query
// ought to be run as a maintenance as near midnight as possible.

$exec = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) < 5 AS ok FROM comment_counters WHERE name='$name';");
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($exec);
mysql_free_result($exec);
$okay = $data['ok'];
if ($okay)
{
   // Okay to post
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment_counters (day, name) VALUES (date(now()), '$name');");
   // Do the rest of the posting
}
else
{
   // Cannot post.
}
```